# Chrome ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED multiple users logged in

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I am able to reproduce an error in Chrome on macOS where I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Step 1: login to user1, browse in Chrome (ok)
Step 2: Lock Screen (do not log out)
Step 3: login to user2, browse in Chrome (ok)
Step 4: Lock Screen (do not log out)
Step 5: login to user1 again, browse in Chrome( not ok).

At step 5 I always get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in Chrome on all sites.  Safari is fine and changing the DNS, changing the wifi connection does not fix the issue.

To fix the issue I must log out of user1, and then login again.

help.